# Jammy 22.04 Firefox Snap Download PDF to Existing Subfolder Fails Silently

Tags: firefox, snap, pdf, downloads, 22.04

In Ubuntu 22.04 Firefox Snap version, I am unable to download PDFs to an existing subfolder using the Download Icon in Firefox's built-in PDF viewer, though it works for a top-level folder; e.g., Desktop or Documents, and works for a new folder created via the Download Dialog.

To reproduce the problem make sure that in Firefox > Settings > General > Files and Applications > Applications you have selected "Open in Firefox" for "Portable Document Format (PDF)."

1. Use Firefox to open a PDF. I've tried it both with a local PDF and one on a web site.
2. Click the Download Icon in the Firefox PDF viewer, then select your Desktop and use the icon to add a new folder, say "test_folder."
3. Save the PDF to test_folder.
4. Use Nautilus to verify that the PDF was saved to test_folder.
5. Delete the PDF from test_folder.
6. Use the Download Icon in Firefox to attempt to save the PDF to test_folder, now that test_folder already exists.
7. Check Nautilus to see if the PDF was saved to test_folder.

For me, the PDF is saved when I create "test_folder" in the Download Dialog, but not when I try to save it to the already existing test_folder, or if I try to save it to any other existing subfolder. There's no error message, and it appears to work, but the files aren't saved.

This was a real treat, because I've been saving PDFs to a number of existing subfolders since I installed 22.04, and since it fails silently, I didn't realize it was happening until today, when a PDF I downloaded wasn't where I downloaded it (or anywhere else).

My workaround is to set Firefox to use the "system default application," which downloads the PDF to my designated download directory and opens it in Document Viewer.

I'm wondering if this is a bug in the snap version of Firefox, or if it's something particular to my setup. Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: You can replace the snap version with PPA, that should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks Archisman, I would like to stay with the snap version as that appears to be the direction that Ubuntu is going. My question at this point is whether or not this is a problem based on my setup, or if it's a reproducible bug.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is yes, [this is reproducible](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=22.04+download+firefox).

It appears that the snap version of Firefox is affected, and it may have something to do with an already fixed-but-not-yet-available in Ubuntu 22.04 in GTK. One workaround, as mentioned above, is to uninstall the snap version of Firefox and go with the PPA version.

Another workaround for some permutations of the problem is to click on the filename in the download dialog, which then allows downloading to an existing subfolder. Or you can wait for the fix...